# how to set a hyperlink to a document in a different repository

Tags: hyperlink

I have a document in a non microsoft repository.  I want to place a link to it, in my sharepoint site.  Is this doable and how would this be done.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a simple hyperlink on a page or a file link in a document library?

Comment: You need to provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

So not sure entirely what you are looking for here.  If you just want to link to the file, then you can do so in a hyperlink on a List as long as you have that in the content type you are using.

However, if you are trying to have the system link to the file for you then you are going to take some more configuration.  You have a couple of options:

1. Search
2. Business Connectivity Services.

You can create a search crawl if the network drives are hosted on a Mid-range system, but made available via windows share.  However, I am guessing this is likely not the case.  If you let us know what the source is we might be able to provide better input.

This brings us to BCS.  With BCS you can create a custom connector that consumes oData from the non-microsoft share.  This is assuming it is a oData producer.  If you want to research creating the oData connector you can review this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163967.aspx

However, again if you can provide us with more information we might be able to give you a more specific in-depth response.